# P(4 < X <12) using Chebyshev's not consistent with the simulation value

Tags: r, statistics, discrete-mathematics

On calculating P(4 < X < 12) using Chebyshev's with mean = 8 and variance = 7.9 the probability turned out to be 0.5 but when running this simulation in R I'm getting 0.79

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

```
nsims=10000
x1=rpois(nsims,8)
mean(x1)
var(x1)
length1 = length(which (x1 < 12))
length2 = length(which (x1 <= 4))
length1
length2
(length1 - length2)/nsims
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your simulation is giving the correct answer. The exact answer for `P(4 < x < 12)` where x is a random variable drawn from a Poisson distribution with a lambda of 8 can be found in R without simulation:

```r
sum(dpois(5:11, 8))
#> [1] 0.7884436
```

Your expectation that the *actual probability* should meet the *lower bound* of Chebyshev's inequality is where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply Chebyshev's inequality over `P(4 < X < 12)`, you will get a lower bound for its probability.

Below is the derivation showing you the reason.

```
  P(4 < X < 12) 
= P(|X-8| < 4) 
= 1 - P(|X-8| >= 4/sqrt(7.9)* sqrt(7.9)) 
>= 1 - (sqrt(7.9)/4)^2 = 0.50625
```